# "Tar-jay" not Target

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, jokes

What does the expression means here.

> Pronouncing it "Tar-Jay" not Target

I have a doubt here because tar means low heroin on urban dictionary. And Jay means a wild beast and also Jay is a singer. 
Is it pun or what?

Comment: http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=6174011e-56a4-421a-8e86-fcd07a15fe58

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a joke, playing on the presumed French pronunciation of the word—perhaps it would be more accurate to spell it Tar-zhay, because the "J" sound is more like the second G in garage, rather than the J in the name Jay. It has nothing to do with the words *tar* or *jay*.

Target is an inexpensive place to shop, but French stores are associated with expensive luxuries. So if you are buying something like clothing or makeup at Target, you can poke fun at yourself by saying that you're going to get them at that fancy French store, Target.

Comment: I always thought it was meant to imply it is an upscale version of Wal-Mart.

Comment: @Kat that sounds like a plausible variation on the general idea, but I don't think a Wal-Mart comparison is the primary connotation; I first heard the joke used in person in two different locations that did not have Wal-Marts (one was a town in the upper Midwest which has since acquired a Wal-Mart and the other was the west side of Los Angeles). I suppose the exact connotations could vary by who's saying it—"she thinks she's too good to shop at Wal-Mart, she only shops at *Targét*" is rather different from "this old thing? I got it at Targét, lol. (Look, it's got pockets!)"